# Assignment of address to integer variable

Tags: c++, variables, memory-address

How come you can assign an address to an integer variable like this,the complier will not give an error. i always though you can only assign integer values to a integer variable

```
int a=0x28ff1c
```

You can do the same for a char variable, the complier will not give a error

```
char b=0x28ff1c
```

It will output on the console screen rubbish value for char b and a random value for int a

```
cout<<b
    <<endl;
cout<<a;
```

Can someone explain to me why there is a difference in the output for char b and int a.
Can someone aslo explain to me why a char variable and integer variable can have addresses assign to it

Comment: `0x28ff1c` _is_ an integer value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number `0x28ff1c` is just the hexadecimal (base-16) representation of the decimal (base-10) number `2686748`. As `cout` defaults to printing decimal values for integers, that is probably the number you got printed.

The case with `char b = 0x28ff1c` is slightly different, because

1. `char` is not large enough to hold that value. The practical result is that it gets truncated to `0x1c`.
2. `cout` treats `char` specially, because it is normally used to hold textual data, so `cout` prints the character that has the code `0x1c`, which is some kind of control character. You could try it with `0x41` for example (which represents `'A'` in ASCII and UTF-8).

And note that there is nothing that marks `0x28ff1c` as being an address. An address would be formed by `&a` or `(void*)0x28ff1c`.

Comment: `(char*)0x28ff1c` is safer (unless you can guarantee `0x28ff1c` is properly aligned for `int`) - cc. @Lim Bonus question - is the result truncated, or is it undefined behavior because of the overflow (take into account that `char` is signed)?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Implementation-defined (unless `CHAR_BIT >= 23`), it could saturate, truncate, map all out-of-range values to 13, the implementation just has to document what it does. In C, it could even raise an implementation-defined signal.

Answer (score 8):

`0x28ff1c` is not an address itself - it's just a hexadecimal number.

The following are equivalent:

```
int a =   2686748;  //decimal number
int a =  0x28ff1c;  //hexadecimal number
int a = 012177434;  //octal number
```

An address is represented by a pointer - if it's just that, an address, you can use a `void*`:

```
void* p = (void*)0x28ff1c;
```

In which case

```
int a = p;
```

wouldn't compile. `p` is an address, the number itself isn't.

Comment: @Luchin how do you explain the difference in output of int a and char b and how come the complier doesnt give a error when assigning a integer value to char b

Comment: @Lim a char is only 1 byte, so it can't hold the whole value. A warning *can* be issued, but it's not required to. You're basically overflowing the `char` variable (so it prints an incorrect result).

Answer (score 1):

Because in any literal starting 0x is actually an integer. So it is allowed. An address <strike>is</strike> can sometimes be an integer.

Comment: Addresses are not integers. In many implementations, it may be possible to convert addresses to integers without issues. In some implementations, addresses may have a structure that is not well represented in a single integer (e.g., adding 1 to the encoding of an address might not produce an address that is 1 byte further in memory).

Comment: Good point @EricPostpischil. I'll say "Sometimes an address can be an integer"

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't see how that's relevant. Granted, an `int` is not guaranteed to hold an address, but pointer arithmetics isn't in question here. What you pointed out (adding to an address) is much more complicated than that (it can even lead to UB).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It is relevant because a statement was made that is false and that fosters an incorrect mental model in people learning programming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil definitely, an address is not an integer. Well, it is, but not an `int`. I wasn't arguing that. Just that there are a lot of nitpicks that can't be fully described in a comment.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Regarding “Well, it is, but not an `int`.” No, that is not correct. On many systems, with flat address spaces, addresses may be essentially equivalent to integers. But there are systems on which they are not. One of the simplest counterexamples is base-offset addressing, where an address is not one integer but is essentially two integers. Then address arithmetic and integer arithmetic differ greatly: Adding one to an address might wrap around within a segment. Subtracting addresses in different segments will not generally produce the number of bytes between them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's new to me. Can you please give me some more resources on that? (I'd love to know more)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sorry, I do not have a reference handy; I did not learn this from modern references; I lived through it. Likely the easiest way to see it today on consumer machines is to try some MS-DOS or early Windows programming. Perhaps MSVC still supports building for old address models. Essentially, an address would be a base and an offset, and the physical address would be something like 64*base+offset.  So base 0 and offset 64 would be the same address as base 1 and offset 0. But there were more complicated address spaces…

Comment: An address could be a segment number and an offset, and the segment number could be an index into a table where a base address would be stored. Then there is no fixed arithmetic from the segment number and offset to the complete address. You would need the table entry as well to form a complete address. “Pointers” in C would have to be formed of compound information. MSVC had (has?) different types of pointers for different situations (long pointers, near pointers, et cetera).

Comment: Two more comments, to add different aspects. Perhaps we should create a new question for these. First, some systems, which I do not know directly, have different types of pointers for different objects. Imagine a machine with 48-bit words that can only be accessed by word number. To handle strings of bytes, the compiler has to invent addresses for bytes within words and generate code to extract or merge bytes. If you use three bits to encode which 8-bit byte within the 48-bit word is wanted, then you only use the values 0-5. 6 and 7 are unused. Then address arithmetic gets weird.

Comment: So address spaces like these are why C and C++ have rules about pointer arithmetic. The rules about performing address arithmetic only within an array? That is so that the compiler does not need to guarantee different objects use the same base for their base+offset address. You can do arithmetic within the array because the array has only one base. Once you go outside the array, simple arithmetic on the base+offset address might fail. The rules about converting pointer types? Those avoid problems with converting byte-within-word addresses to word addresses, and so on.

Comment: I posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091855/what-memory-address-spaces-are-there) to gather information about address spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `*(int *)(Address) = value` as a construct to assigne a `value` to `Address` and use the answer by @Luchian Grigore