# Differences in assignment of integer variable

Tags: c++, variables, variable-assignment

I just asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091203/assignment-of-address-to-integer-variable) and it got me thinking if there is any reason

1)why you would assign a int variable using hexidecimal or octal instead of decimal and

2)what are the difference between the different way of assignment

```
int a=0x28ff1c;  // hexideciaml
int a=10;        //decimal (the most commonly used way)
int a=012177434; // octal
```

Comment: In the end, it's just zeros and ones.

Comment: In embedded development data sheets often use hex.  octal is rarely used though in my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You may have some constants that are more easily understood when written in hexadecimal.

   Bitflags, for example, in hexadecimal are compact and easily (for some values of easily) understood, since there's a direct correspondence 4 binary digits => 1 hex digit - for this reason, in general the hexadecimal representation is useful when you are doing bitwise operations (e.g. masking).

   In a similar fashion, in several cases integers may be internally divided in some fields, for example often colors are represented as a 32 bit integer that goes like this: `0xAARRGGBB` (or `0xAABBGGRR`); also, IP addresses: each piece of IP in the dotted notation is two hexadecimal digits in the "32-bit integer" notation (usually in such cases `unsigned` integers are used to avoid messing with the sign bit).

   In some code I'm working on at the moment, for each pixel in an image I have a single byte to use to store "accessory information"; since I have to store some flags and a small number, I use the least significant 4 bits to store the flags, the 4 most significant ones to store the number. Using hexadecimal notations it's immediate to write the appropriate masks and shifts: `byte & 0x0f` gives me the 4 LS bits for the flags, `(byte & 0xf0)>>4` gives me the 4 MS bits (re-shifted in place).

   I've never seen octal used for anything besides [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) and UNIX permissions masks (although in the last case they are actually useful, as you probably know if you ever used `chmod`); probably their inclusion in the language comes from the fact that C was initially developed as the language to write UNIX.
2. <s>By default, integer literals are of type `int`, while hexadecimal literals are of type `unsigned int` or larger if `unsigned int` isn't large enough to hold the specified value. So, when assigning a hexadecimal literal to an `int` there's an implicit conversion (although it won't impact the performance, any decent compiler will perform the cast at compile time).</s> Sorry, brainfart. I checked the standard right now, it goes like this:

   - decimal literals, without the `u` suffix, are always signed; their type is the smallest that can represent them between `int`, `long int`, `long long int`;
   - octal and hexadecimal literals without suffix, instead, may also be of `unsigned` type; their actual type is the smallest one that can represent the value between `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.

   (C++11, §2.14.2, ¶2 and Table 6)

   The difference may be relevant for overload resolution<sup>1</sup>, but it's not particularly important when you are just assigning a literal to a variable. Still, keep in mind that you may have valid integer constants that are larger than an `int`, i.e. assignment to an `int` will result in signed integer overflow; anyhow, any decent compiler should be able to warn you in these cases.

---

1. Let's say that on our platform integers are in 2's complement representation, `int` is 16 bit wide and long is 32 bit wide; let's say we have an overloaded function like this:

   ```
   void a(unsigned int i)
   {
       std::cout<<"unsigned";
   }

   void a(int i)
   {
       std::cout<<"signed";
   }
   ```

   Then, calling `a(1)` and `a(0x1)` will produce the same result (`signed`), but `a(32768)` will print `signed` and `a(0x10000)` will print `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

**It matters from a readability standpoint - which one you choose expresses your intention.**

If you're treating the variable as an integral type, you know, like `2+2=4`, you use the decimal representation. It's intuitive and straight-forward.

If you're using it as a bitmask, you can use hexa, octal or even binary. For example, you'll know

```
int a = 0xFF;
```

will have the last 8 bits set to `1`. You'll know that

```
int a = 0xF0;
```

is `(...)11110000`, but you couldn't directly say the same thing about

```
int a = 240;
```

although they are equivalent. It just depends on what you use the numbers for.

Answer (score 0):

well the truth is it doesn't matter if you want it on decimal, octal or hexadecimal its just a representation and for your information, numbers in computers are stored in binary(so they are just 0's and 1's) which you can use also to represent a number. so its just a matter of representation and readability.

**NOTE:**
Well in some of C++ debuggers(in my experience) I assigned a number as a decimal representation but in my debugger it is shown as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to the assignment of and integer this way:

```
int a = int(5);
int b(6);
int c = 3;
```

it's all about preference, and when it breaks down you're just doing the same thing. Some might choose octal or hex to go along with their program that manipulates that type of data.